# Como centralizar uma div com a largura auto?

Tags: css

Tenho uma div dentro do footer, mas ela é expansível na largura, como faço para centralizar? Já usei margin: 0 auto; mas não foi.

```
<footer class="rodape">
    <div class="centralizar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: posta um exemplo aí com o css do que tu fez

Comment: footer.rodape > aside.footer-down > .partners { width: auto; margin: auto; } essa é a div que quero centralizar

Comment: footer.rodape > aside.footer-down {
 margin: auto;
 width: 950px;
 height: 50px;
 display: table;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
} essa é aonde ta o rodapé

Comment: Se não funcionou com `margin: 0 auto;` é por algum outro problema na sua página. Se não puser o CSS na pergunta, fica complicado de alguém responder.

Comment: Neste caso você pode remover a pergunta, ou postar a solução como resposta, se achar que pode ser útil para outras pessoas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provalmente o problema de não estar centralizando a div é a questão de que sua class 'rodape' não tem uma width definida e o mesmo vale para a div 'centralizar'...

```css
.rodape{
  width:100%; 
  background:red
}
.centralizar{
  width:80%;
  background:gray;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:20px
}
```

```html
<footer class="rodape">
    <div class="centralizar">qualquer coisa aqui</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se quer uma *div* responsiva que se auto ajuste e ela continue centralizada utilize o seguinte css:

```
.centralizar{width:20%; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Caso queira aumentar a div é só aumentar a porcetagem do width.
Lembre-se a posição e relativa a estrutura do html feita.